# Keep specif value and remove other values from an array php

Tags: php

I have an array of dates. I need to keep one date and remove others.How can i do that?

I tries `array_search` but it is not working.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2019-05-27
    [1] => 2019-05-28
    [2] => 2019-05-29
    [3] => 2019-05-30
    [4] => 2019-05-31
    [5] => 2019-06-01
)
```

I just want to keep `2019-05-30` only. How can i do that?

What I tried :

```
if (($key = array_search($val, $array)) == false) { 
    unset($array[$key]); 
}
```

Comment: What did you tried?

Comment: if (($key = array_search($val, $array)) == false) {
    unset($array[$key]);
}

Comment: If that is what you have tried, please add it to you r question, and not as a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_search()` will work fine in your case

```
$key = array_search('2019-05-30',$array);
$array = array($array[$key]);

print_r($array);
```

Output: https://3v4l.org/GftvF

***Note:*** In case you want to preserve the original key then do:

```
$array = array($key=>$array[$key]);
```

Output:-https://3v4l.org/qeKEH